# More specific / details DIFF data

Tags: bash, shell, logging, scripting, diff

I am currently running a networking device and an emulation of the networking device and running a number of commands on both to compare how closely my emulated device behaves to the original.

I have a script that runs the following:

```
diff -q /tmp/offline_output /tmp/online_output 1>/dev/null
    if [[ $? == "0" ]]; then
        echo "PASSED: $cmd"
        #cat /tmp/online_output 
        #cat /tmp/offline_output 
    else
        echo "FAILED: $cmd"
        echo "---------------------------------" >> failure_log
        echo "FAILURE: $cmd " >> failure_log
        diff -c /tmp/offline_output /tmp/online_output >> failure_log
        echo "" >> failure_log
        echo "" >> failure_log
    fi
```

In order to determine the variation in the commands. However, I'm finding this can be incredibly subtle in very long lines of text (a single integer slightly different).

ex.

```
!  cookie=0x3abb8bc, table=18, priority=129,ipv6,reg14=0x6,metadata=0x1,ipv6_dst=fe80::/64 actions=dec_ttl(),load:0->OXM_OF_PKT_REG4[32..47],move:NXM_NX_IPV6_DST[]->NXM_NX_XXREG0[],load:0x8580afffef40201->NXM_NX_XXREG1[0..63],load:0xfe80000000000000->NXM_NX_XXREG1[64..127],mod_dl_src:0a:58:0a:f4:02:01,load:0x6->NXM_NX_REG15[],load:0x1->NXM_NX_REG10[0],resubmit(,19)
...
!  cookie=0x3abb8bc, table=18, priority=129,ipv6,reg14=0x6,metadata=0x1,ipv6_dst=fe80::/64 actions=dec_ttl,load:0->OXM_OF_PKT_REG4[32..47],move:NXM_NX_IPV6_DST[]->NXM_NX_XXREG0[],load:0x8580afffef40201->NXM_NX_XXREG1[0..63],load:0xfe80000000000000->NXM_NX_XXREG1[64..127],mod_dl_src:0a:58:0a:f4:02:01,load:0x6->NXM_NX_REG15[],load:0x1->NXM_NX_REG10[0],resubmit(,19)
```

In long blocks of logs picking out these subtle differences is proving challenging.

Is there a better way to do this? I feel like there must be. I've tried different options with diff, but nothing has really stood out as a great solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe `meld(1)` can work for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you have `git` installed, you can use it to display differences in color (Even if the files in question aren't being tracked by `git`):

```sh
if cmp /tmp/offline_output /tmp/online_output; then
  echo "PASSED: $cmd"
else
  echo "FAILED: $cmd"
  ( echo "---------------------------------"
    echo "FAILURE: $cmd "
    git diff --no-index --color=always --word-diff=color --word-diff-regex='[^,]+' /tmp/offline_output /tmp/online_output
  ) >> failure_log
fi
```

You'd have to then look at the file in something that renders ANSI terminal color codes to easily see the changes.

Also note using `cmp` for the initial test to see if the files differ, and using it directly as the `if` test case instead of looking at `$?`, and how I changed the redirection to `failure_log` to have all relevant commands output to it without having to redirect each individual one.